# Bootstrap modal: is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal in my page. When I try to call it when the windows load, it prints an error to the console that says :

```
$(...).modal is not a function
```

This is my Modal HTML :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="prizePopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                This Modal title
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Add some text here
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Submit changes
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

And this is my JavaScript to run it with when a window is loaded :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#prizePopup').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: write your modal trigger code in window ready function

Comment: " $(window).load(function() { "  saved me

Comment: By defining the JQuery instance twice the problem will arrise. <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You have an issue in scripts order. Load them in this order:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- BS JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Have fun using Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#prizePopup').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Why this? Because [Bootstrap JS depends on jQuery](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-individual-compiled):

> ### Plugin dependencies
>
> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. **Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery** (this means **jQuery must be included before the plugin files**).

Comment: I still have this problem when I try to run the modal using google dev tools.

Comment: @CodedContainer Make sure `$` is the jQuery function. Most probably it's the `querySelector` function (named `$`) which is exposed by the Google Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: you deserve a thums up

Comment: NOTE: bootstrap 5 dropped jQuery, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508864/getting-type-error-modal-is-not-a-function#:~:text=Bootstrap%20V5%20has%20many%20breaking%20changes.%20One%20of%20them%20is%20the%20removal%20of%20jquery)

Answer (score 98):

This warning may also be shown if jQuery is declared more than once in your code. The second jQuery declaration prevents bootstrap.js from working correctly.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
...
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for this point ,i met this issue and found that my own DataTable.min.js had imported jquery libraries into it ,but my page import it again ,that's the root issue caused it .

Comment: Very good hint, I had jquery npm installed in Aurelia and also manually loaded in index.html. Thanks!

Comment: In a large framework on which Im working, with horrible setup, jQuery's loaded in some pages but in others: after banging my head a couple of times, went here and read @Nurp answer. Saved my day.

Comment: The problem is i am using application that has dependencies on older jquery version and i am not allowed to change and it is being imported later at some stage ! i have used latest version of jquery and then bootstrap js , causing all the problems !

Comment: That was my problem, too. I removed jquery from the scripts section in angular.js and also deleted "import * as $ from 'jquery'" from the Typescript and everything worked.

Comment: Era meu problema também ! Obrigado !

Comment: Essa é uma boa resposta. Foi atolado por isso por algum tempo.

Answer (score 28):

**Causes for TypeError: $(…).modal is not a function:**

1. Scripts are loaded in the wrong order.
2. Multiple jQuery instances

**Solutions:**

1. In case, if a script attempt to access an element that hasn't been
   reached yet then you will get an error. Bootstrap depends on jQuery,
   so jQuery must be referenced first. So, you must be called the
   jquery.min.js and then bootstrap.min.js and further the bootstrap
   Modal error is actually the result of you not including bootstrap's javascript before 
   calling the modal function. Modal is defined in
   bootstrap.js and not in jQuery. So the script should be included in this manner

   ```
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   ```
2. In case if there are multiple instances of jQuery, the second jQuery 
   declaration prevents bootstrap.js from working correctly. so make use of
   `jQuery.noConflict();` before calling the modal popup

   ```
   jQuery.noConflict();
   $('#prizePopup').modal('show');
   ```

   jQuery event aliases like `.load`, `.unload` or `.error` deprecated since jQuery 1.8.

   ```
   $(window).on('load', function(){ 
         $('#prizePopup').modal('show');
   });
   ```

   OR try opening the modal popup directly

   ```
   $('#prizePopup').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
         ...
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, in my case I was loading two instances of jQuery.

Comment: I change to grasp the modal directly by `$(".modalClassName")` and it works...

Answer (score 17):

jQuery should be the first:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 16):

The problem is due to having jQuery instances more than one time. Take care if you are using many files with multiples instance of jQuery. Just leave 1 instance of jQuery and your code will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

change the order of the script

Because bootstrap is a jquery plugin so it require Jquery to execute

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
$('#prizePopup').modal('toggle');
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me.., I'm importing multiple jquery libs : `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/`, and `code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0`

Answer (score 8):

Struggled to solve this one, checked the load order and if jQuery was included twice via bundling, but that didn't seem to be the cause.

Finally fixed it by making the following change:

(before):

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

(after):

```
window.$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Found the answer here: https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/issues/685

Answer (score 6):

Changing import statement worked. From

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

to:

```
declare var $ : any;
```

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
npm i @types/jquery
npm install -D @types/bootstrap
```

in the project to add the jquery types in your Angular Project. After that include

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
```

in your app.module.ts

Add

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your index.html just before the body closing tag.

And if you are running Angular 2-7 include "**jquery**" in the types field of tsconfig.app.json file.

This will remove all error of 'modal' and '$' in your Angular project.

Answer (score 4):

I meet this error when integrate modal bootstrap in angular.

This is my solution to solve this issue.

I share for whom concern.

First step you need install `jquery` and `bootstrap` by `npm` command.

Second you need add `declare var $ : any;` in component

And use can use `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` on onSave() method

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-model-bootstrap-close?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party, however there's an important note:

Your scripts might be in the right order but watch out for any `async`s in your script tag (like this)

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js" async></script>`

This might be causing the issue. Especially if you have this `async` set only for Production environments this can get really frustrating to reason about.

Comment: The code in the question clearly shows that (a) they are not in the right order and (b) they are not using the async attribute

Comment: I'm giving my answer because it is a frequently googled question and someone might benefit from it

Answer (score 2):

I added a modal dialog in **jsp** and tried to open it with javascript in **jsx** and hit the same error: **"...modal is not a function"**

In my case, simply by adding the missing import to the jsx solved the problem.

```
`import "./../bower/bootstrap/js/modal.js"; // or import ".../bootstrap.min.js"`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened to me just in production just because I imported jquery with HTTP and not HTTPS (and production is HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery.noConflict();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $('#prizePopup').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer, seeing as how `noConflict()` can have adverse effects (it relinquishes jQuery's control of `$`). Please explain why this works, and what caveats it may come with. Also refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the close button
I added class  to close button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Then trigger in a function

```
$(".close-modal").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is calling the modal creation directly via Javascript:

```
 var modal = new bootstrap.Modal('#wait')
 modal.show(); 
 ...
 modal.hide();
```