# Auto open modal by appending variable to selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've taken the code from the bootstrap site  to come up with the following function which needs to auto open a selected modal if the int: ModalId is not 0.
In Vis studio there is a syntax error red line under the ')' before .modal, and in the chrome debugger it says 'uncaught type error, $(...).modal is not a function'.  What am I doing wrong please?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       if (@Model.ModalId != 0) {
           $('#accepted_'+@Model.ModalId).modal('show');
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function) it is important to place the dependencies in the proper order.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       if (@Model.ModalId != 0) {
           $('#accepted_'+@Model.ModalId).modal('show');
       }
      });
    </script>
```

If this is not the case, plz add more code.

Comment: Great it's working thanks! I don't know how many times I've gone looking into complicated solutions to the problem when I've missed the obvious first step.  Gotta stop doing that.  Since the modal was already working I didn't think it was needing any extra script file references, but now I see modal('show') needed bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: I had similar problems myself. We tent to search the improbable, when the simple thinks cause the problems.Glad i helped. If you want accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add bootstrap.min.js in your index.html file.