# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jquery script to show modal form

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".manipulate").click(function(){
        $('#id_description').val();
        var item_keys = ['#id_counter', '#id_first_name','#id_middle_name', '#id_last_name', '#id_display_name', '#id_field', '#id_loa_price', '#id_basic_cert_price', '#id_written_appraisal_cost']
        for(var i=1; i<12; i++){
            var item_val = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child('+i+')')[0].innerText;
            console.log("InnerText is :"+ item_val);
            $(item_keys[i-1]).val(item_val);
        }
        $('#id_item').val($(this).attr('item_id'));
        $('#edititemModal').modal("show");
    });
});
</script>
```

If i click the edit button to show the modal form i get .modal not a function.

Comment: If you add the mark up, it will be very useful.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jn81w7ym/1/, make sure you are including bootstrap correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal: is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

not

```
<script>
```

Also follow the right order:
[Bootstrap modal: is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function)

Comment: As of HTML 5, the `type` attribute is (a) optional (b) explicitly advised against using for script elements containing JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

I resolved it after adding the library inside the index.js.We think you need this liabrary,bootstrap.js please add inside the index.js and i hope your code works will fine.