# $(...).modal is not a function in module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realise this question has been asked a few times but none of the solutions in previous questions have resolved my issue.

I am trying to hide a modal using:
    `$('#modal').modal('hide')`

but am getting:
`$(...).modal is not a function`
in the console.

**However if I go into the developer console and enter:**
    `$('#modal').modal('hide')`
**it works perfectly**

I am getting jQuery/bootstrap via a CDN in the index.html and have checked the order of the imports and checked for multiple imports of jQuery.

EDIT: My jQuery/bootstrap scripts are being loaded at the top of the index.html and the JS module is included at the bottom of the page so the order seems correct. `$('#modal').modal('hide')` is being called on a `$(window).on('resize')` event

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of your HTML to the question?

Comment: This means that you load bootstrap js after you call `.modal()` method. Thus in a console you can use it, but not in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal: is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski my jQuery/bootstrap scripts are being loaded at the top of the index.html and the JS module is included at the bottom of the page so the order seems correct. 

`$('#modal').modal('hide')` is being called on a `$(window).on('resize')` event

Comment: Some frameworks rerender the page when the window is resized. Not sure if that's the case with bootstrap though, but if so that might cause the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter in developer console and it works means, problem with document ready issue or javascript placement issue.

just try this to confirm.

```
$(function(){
   $('#modal').modal('hide');
});
```

If this working, then document ready issue.

another one is you should use this `$('#modal').modal('hide');` after jquery-ui.js.

Please provide your code sample for further investigation.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it did not work. `$('#modal').modal('hide');` is being called on a `$(window).on('resize')` event.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ $('#modal').modal('hide'); },800);

Comment: Just try above one.