# JavaScript: How to call Bootstrap Modal from inside function?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function on click of a link which will display modal.

Imported Scripts in `head` tag

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modFileUpload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Upload Plans</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form id="myform">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="myfile">
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeUploadPlansModal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link:

```
<a class="nav-link text-left"  role="button" onclick="uploadFiles()" >
                  <i class="fa fa-upload"></i><span class="nav-text">Upload Plans</span>
                  </a>
```

uploadFiles function:

```
function uploadFiles(){
    $('#modFileUpload').modal('show'); //getting error here
}
```

I am getting error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Is there any way to show modal onclick of link?

Comment: Can you post your code where you are importing bootstrap.js and etc?

Comment: You either haven't loaded bootstrap.js or have loaded jQuery.js more than once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap modal: is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated question with my import scripts, Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure there isn't some other version of jQuery.js loading further down the page. Another issue could be some other library using `$()` and it is no longer jQuery object

Comment: You could alternatively add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modFileUpload"` to the anchor element that calls `uploadFiles()`

Comment: Also, consider using the template  from the [bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue because I had imported the cdn scripts in my `head` tag as well as before `body` tag.

And in my case all were of different version.

Your `head` tag imports should look like this:

```
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And make sure there shouldn't be any other bootstrap, jquery scripts in your code.

Comment: Be careful with slim version of jQuery if wanting to use ajax or any of the other api's that it does not include that the full version does