# Datatable button aiming to different Modal with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

It is a table display in webpage, it displays one button for row using Datatable.
In the column #4 displays either of 2 values, one is `---` which is desires for trigger any of the two Modals after click over it own row's button.

When click over any row's button, `console.log` successfully display message set, however it does not open any modal and display error `document.getElementById(...).modal is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>`

Table header is `['eamil', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'NIT', 'button']`
data value for table is:

```
[['prueba1@gmail.com','Daniel','Apellido01','907595-0'],
['prueba4@gmail.com','Prueba04','Apellido04','---']]
```

HTML

```
<!-- DataTable -->
<table id="listados" class="display nowrap responsive" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for i in header %}
            <th>{{ i }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for i in evnts %}
        <tr>
            <td class="text-dark">{{ i[0] }}</td>
            <td class="text-dark">{{ i[1] }}</td>
            <td class="text-dark">{{ i[2] }}</td>
            {% if i[3] != '---' %}
            <td class="text-dark">{{ i[3] }}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td class="text-dark">{{ i[3] }}</td>
            {% endif %}
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            {% for i in header %}
            <th>{{ i }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<!-- Modals -->

<div class="modal fade" id="newNit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newNitModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="newNitModalLabel">Agregar Nuevo NIT</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="nuevo"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="borrar">Continuar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>       
<div class="modal fade" id="actualizarNit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="actualizarNitModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="actualizarNitModalLabel">Actualizar informacion NIT</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="update"> </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="borrar">Continuar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

snippet for Datatable and modals

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var pasarValor;
    var table = $('#listados').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button class='btn-success' data-toggle='modal' id='agregarNit'>NIT</button>"
                }
            ],
        "scrollX":true,
    })
    $('#listados #agregarNit').on('click', function() {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            pasarValor = {
                mail: data[0],
                nit: data[3]
                };
        
        if (data[3] === '---'){
            console.log('True')
            document.getElementById('newNit').modal('show');
        } else {
            console.log('False')
            document.getElementById('actualizarNit').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, you have typo in your code remove `#` from `getElementById('#newNit')` as well from next one as you are already using `getElementById`.

Comment: Hi @Swati, thank for the tip, after change it the the error is `document.getElementById(...).modal is not a function at HTMLButtonElement. <anonymous>` I changed it in Question

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function) should be helpful.