# how fix "modal is not a function" in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

Hello everyone I got this error: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function".
[modal is not a fuction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdkuB.png)
Here is my code in welcome.blade.php:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{-- This is the vue component --}}
        <new-arrivals></new-arrivals>
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my js/app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'
import { VueCtkDateTimePicker } from 'vue-ctk-date-time-picker';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
import 'vue-ctk-date-time-picker/dist/vue-ctk-date-time-picker.css';
// import $ from 'jquery';
// window.$ = $;
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.swal = swal;
Vue.component('VueCtkDateTimePicker', VueCtkDateTimePicker);
Vue.component('new-arrivals', require('./components/NewArrivals.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Here is my vue script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data(){
      return {
      }
  },
  methods: {  
    openModal(){
        $('#create_form_modal').modal('show');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like `js/app.js` uses JQuery and its loaded before JQuery script. Hence, change the order of the JS files will fix it. first call `jquery-3.6.0.min.js` and then `js/app.js`.

Comment: Try to add a `defer` attribute on you jquery script as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar issue: [Bootstrap modal: is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function)

The reason for this problem was the wrong loading order of the scripts. Try to do this in that order

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```